# How to create a unique list from a list containing duplicate items java

Tags: java

Please read it completely. I am trying to find all unique items in a list and copy them to another list by following the below condition:
I have a POJO class like this:

```
class MyObject {
    String name;
    int id;
    int quantity;

    public MyObject(String s1,int id, int s2) {
        this.name = s1;
        this.id = id;
        this.quantity = s2;
     }
}
```

I have an `ArrayList` containing duplicate objects of the above class. I want to copy all the unique objects to the new `ArrayList` but all the unique objects `quantity` will increase according to the number of duplicate elements in the first list. How to achieve this?

e.g: If the duplicate list contains 2 objects with id as 1. Then new list will contain 1 object with its quantity increased to 2.

My code:

```
Set<Card> uniqueRefundItems = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (Card lcp : refundList) {
   if (uniqueRefundItems.contains(lcp)) {
       lcp.setQuantity(lcp.getQuantity() + 1);
   } else {
       lcp.setQuantity(1);

   }
   uniqueRefundItems.add(lcp);
}
```

But as I am doing a **deep copy**. Its not working. Any other approach to do the same?

Comment: On paper what you have as far as code seems to be logical.  What issue did you run into or what was the error you encountered with this?  (Are you sure that `Card` has `equals` and `hashCode` defined?)

Comment: As I did deep copy. The `contains` is not working for checking equality. Not it doesnt have.

Comment: You should *probably* show what code you have for `equals` and `hashCode` for your `Card` class.  At this point I get the suspicion that you're hashing or checking on quantity as well, which may be the cause of lots of false positives.

Comment: Are you allowed to define `equals` and `hashCode` or is `Card` a white-box class that cannot be altered?

Comment: Added my POJO class @Makoto

Comment: So equals is true if any of 4 ids matches any of 4 ids?

Comment: But that is not working @Compass

Comment: Are we guaranteed that if one ID matches, the other 3 IDs will match, and that all ID fields are non-null?

Comment: All ID field are non-null. Not sure about all the ID's will match @Compass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a list of unique objects with quantity updated

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyObject("AAA", 1, 0));
list.add(new MyObject("CCC", 3, 0));
list.add(new MyObject("AAA", 1, 0));
list.add(new MyObject("BBB", 2, 0));
list.add(new MyObject("AAA", 1, 0));

Map<Integer, MyObject> temp = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach( x -> {
    MyObject o = temp.get(x.id);
   if (o == null) {
        temp.put(x.id, x);
        x.quantity = 1;
    } else {
        o.quantity++;
    }
});
List<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<>(temp.values());
```

Note that this answer is for the MyObject code example in the question. When adding a new object to the `temp` map I set quantity to 1 since that is how it is handled in the question but it could be argued that a better logic is needed.

Comment: I didnt do it. But I will check your answer. Btw I added my actual POJO class

Comment: `x.quantity++` should only occur if we assume `x.quantity` does not already include itself.

Comment: The mechanics of the OP's code are laregly okay.  What's missing is a coherent implementation of equals and hashCode, so presenting streams as a solution only adds more complexity, and is thus unhelpful.

Comment: @Compass, I assumed `quantity` would be zero from start but that is a good observation

Comment: Any possible way to achieve this without involving the `hashCode` and `equals`. I tried overriding them and its not working.

Comment: @sagarsuri my answer is not dependant of `hashCode` and `equals`

Comment: @Makoto my solution is based on the `MyObject` class

Comment: That's not my point - the main body of work of amalgamating the items together as presented in the OP's original body of work would be fine if it were the case that there was a suitable equals or hashCode method.

Comment: @sagarsuri Any feedback on this?

Comment: Little changes I did to your algorithm. And it worked like charm. If o==null than I was setting the quantity to 1 before adding the object to LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is close to correct.

The code below is an "old school" (i.e. no streams) approach to this:

```
// don't have setters in this object.
public class MyObject
{
  private final int id;
  private final String name;
  private int quantity;

  public MyObject(final int theId, final String theName)
  {
    id = theId;
    name = theName;

    quantity = 1;
  }

  public void incrementQuantity()
  {
    quantity += 1;
  }

  public int getId() { ... }
  public String getName() { ... }
  public int getQuantity() { ... }

  public boolean equals(final Object other)
  {
    // normal equals with 1 small caveat: only compare id and name to determine equals.
  }
}

public List<MyObject> blam(final List<MyObject> refundList)
{
  final List<MyObject> returnValue = new LinkedList<>();
  final Map<MyObject, MyObject> thingMap = new HashMap<>();

  for (final MyObject currentRefund : refundList)
  {
    final MyObject thing = thingMap.get(currentRefund);

    if (thing != null)
    {
      thing.incrementQuantity();
    }
    else
    {
      thingMap.put(currentRefund, currentRefund);
    }
  }

  returnValue.addAll(thingMap.values());

  returnReturnValue;
}
```

Edit: fixed the `put`

Comment: I used MyObject as my example. The actual POJO class is down below in the question. I will surely try to follow your approach for this.

Comment: Maps don't `add`.  They `put` a key-value pair.  You mean to use a set?